# Adjusting mean for very small population size

Tags: descriptive-statistics, small-sample, finite-population

I have survey data from 8 respondents out of a population of 10 (very small I know). I know that FPC applies as we have more than 5% of the population in the sample.

I can calculate the mean for a 0-10 scale at 7.7 I know that the FPC applies in adjusting the confidence interval around the mean, but do I need to make any adjustments to the mean?

Comment: what's FPC here?

Comment: Finite Population Correction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Correction_for_finite_population

Comment: Maybe adjust your expectations not to expect short confidence intervals from such small samples.